# SharedPreferences to save more than one values returning null while retriving

Tags: android, null, sharedpreferences

```
public abstract class CartSharedPrefrences {
    public static boolean addFavoriteItem(Activity activity,String favoriteItem){
        //Get previous favorite items
        String favoriteList = getStringFromPreferences(activity,null,"favorites");
        // Append new Favorite item
        if(favoriteList!=null){
            favoriteList = favoriteList+","+favoriteItem;
        }else{
            favoriteList = favoriteItem;
        }
        // Save in Shared Preferences
        return putStringInPreferences(activity,favoriteList,"favorites");
    }
    public static String[] getFavoriteList(Activity activity){
        String favoriteList = getStringFromPreferences(activity,null,"favorites");
        return convertStringToArray(favoriteList); 
    }
    private static boolean putStringInPreferences(Activity activity,String nick,String key){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = activity.getPreferences(Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(key, nick);
        editor.commit();
        return true;
    }
    private static String getStringFromPreferences(Activity activity,String defaultValue,String key){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = activity.getPreferences(Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String temp = sharedPreferences.getString(key, defaultValue);
        return temp;
    }

    private static String[] convertStringToArray(String str){
        String[] arr =str.split(",");
        return arr;
    }
}
```

i have tried out above solution, while debugging it saves data to shared 
preferences but when i am trying to retrieve data from shared preferences it 
will returning null, while adding data to shared preferences it is retrieving 
the method to check if previously any data available in shared preferences or 
not, at that time that method it returning the data for checking purpose, but 
while calling from another activity it is returning null. can anyone help me? 
how to get the perfect values from it. thanks in advance.

Comment: `but while calling from another activity it is returning null.` ... *public SharedPreferences getPreferences (int mode)

Added in API level 1
Retrieve a SharedPreferences object for accessing preferences that are  **private to this activity.***

Comment: i have tried http://stackoverflow.com/a/9054246/5324829 solution but its returning null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a private mode :

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = activity.getPreferences(Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

If you want to share the preferences between activities, you could use :

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the solution, now it is working properly as i want.