# How to use SharedPreferences to save more than one Integer values?

Tags: android, arraylist, android-sharedpreferences

I want to store more than one Integer Values in Shared Preference. Is this possible to do it?

Comment: Yes you can add int values in arraylist and store arraylist in sp.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9054193/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-to-save-more-than-one-values

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use SharedPreferences to save more than one values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9054193/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-to-save-more-than-one-values)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I store an integer array in SharedPreferences?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7175880/how-can-i-store-an-integer-array-in-sharedpreferences)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For saving in `SharedPreferences`:

```
public void putListInt(String key, ArrayList<Integer> intList) {
    checkForNullKey(key);
    Integer[] myIntList = intList.toArray(new Integer[intList.size()]);
    preferences.edit().putString(key, TextUtils.join("‚‗‚", myIntList)).apply();
}
```

For retrieving from `SharedPreferences`:

```
public ArrayList<Integer> getListInt(String key) {
    String[] myList = TextUtils.split(preferences.getString(key, ""), "‚‗‚");
    ArrayList<String> arrayToList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(myList));
    ArrayList<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (String item : arrayToList)
        newList.add(Integer.parseInt(item));

    return newList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Set(form Java Collection) to store more than one Integer values in Shared Preferences.

Comment: There is no method to putintSet("key", set);
Not work for me. I don't understand the programmers logic because sawal gandum r jawab channa hota hy.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Gson for storing array in SharedPreferences

For storing value.

```
int[] list = new int[10];
String string=new Gson().toJson(list);
prefs.edit().putString("data", string).apply();
```

For fetching value.

```
String data=prefs.getString("data",null);
int [] list=new Gson().fromJson(data,int[].class);
```