# SharedPreference between activity and service

Tags: java, android

I want to make a step counter on Android with TYPE_STEP_COUNTER.As you know,
TYPE_STEP_COUNTER will reset when you re-boot the device.So I should conserve the steps.I decide to use SharedPreference to conserve it.
The project structure as follows:
[image]

In the MainActivity.java，

```js
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        text_step = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.main_text_step);
        delayHandler = new Handler(this);
        Toolbar toolbar=(Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=getSharedPreferences("DateStep",MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    }
```

But ,when I put data in StepService.java,it failed.
//StepService.java

> editor.putInt("step",StepDetector.CURRENT_STEP); 
>   editor.putString("date",current_Date);

It says can't resolve symbol editor.
can you give me some advive what should I do to conserve data in StepService.java?

When I declared in service.java,it shows as follows:
[image]

Comment: You should probably show more of the actual problem code so we have more context. Also, don't use snippets for java code. Just use code blocks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to declare your `editor` outside `onCreate` to make it visible to other methods because currently the declaration limits it's scope to only inside `onCreate` method , in short it's a `Local` reference variable

```
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor; 
  // ^^^^^^^^^^  declare it outside

  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        text_step = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.main_text_step);
        delayHandler = new Handler(this);
        Toolbar toolbar=(Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        editor=getSharedPreferences("DateStep",MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        // initialize editor
    }
```

To use `editor` in other class then declare and initialize it as shown above while using the same file name `DateStep` to save data in that file.

In Service class , `override` [`onCreate`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onCreate()) in `service` and apply the same approach

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor; 
// ^^^^^^^^^^  declare it outside

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    editor=getSharedPreferences("DateStep",MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        // initialize editor
}
```

Comment: When I changed as you told me,the same mistake happens.Service.java still can't recognize editor.

Comment: It's not an issue of using it in other methods. The issue seems to be it not being declared in a *different class*

Comment: you have to declare your `editor` in different class as well as shown above , or you can create a utility class , which uses the context to save passed data to preference

Comment: It doesn't need (and shouldn't be) declared outside of `onCreate()` if that's the only place it's being used in that class.

Comment: Can editor be declared in service.java not in activity?

Comment: it can be , without any issue , try it and look at [this also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9054193/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-to-save-more-than-one-values) plus follow the above advise everywhere in your code

Comment: All I will use the editor is in service including put and get.

Comment: don't forget to override `oncreate` method in service to initialize the preference

Comment: as i said `override` `oncreate` method in service and move that code inside `oncreate` , type `oncreate`  in your service and select the option and press enter to override it

Comment: Do you mean it must be declared in onCreate function?

Comment: yup , there is `oncreate` in `service` as well , just override it , confirm here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onCreate()

Answer (score 2):

You need to commit your changes.

```
editor.putInt("step",StepDetector.CURRENT_STEP);
editor.putString("date",current_Date);
editor.apply(); // <-- Save the data in the Shared Preferences.
```

Then in your service you can get the Shared Preferences again and get the values.
You don't need to share the editor across the two classes. In the `StepService` just request the Shared Preferences again:

```
Context mContext = context;
// ...

mContext.getSharedPreferences("DateStep",MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
// Then get the data you want.
```

### Edit

```
// In StepService

Editor mEditor;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate(); 
    mEditor = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("DateStep",MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    // Then get the data you want anywhere in your Service
}
```

Comment: The problem is service.java can't read variable editor defined in mainActivity.java

Comment: Of course. Precisely because it's defined in the Activity. Just get an another instance of the editor. I've updated my answer above

Comment: All I will use the editor is in service including put and get.So can I only declared it in service?

Comment: If you only use it in service then, yes, just declare, initialize, and use it there

Comment: You can get the Application Context (`getApplicationContext()`) in a Service. Then because the Shared Preferences are accessible from anywhere in the application you can retrieve your data

Answer (score 2):

I would use an interface to communicate Activity and Service: it's makes code cleaner, easier to read and test. If you have never used them, it may be a bit confusing, but take a minute to understand the code:

ServiceCallback.java

```
public interface ServiceCallback {
    void updateStepValue(int value, String date);
}
```

StepService.java

```
public class StepService extends Service {
   ServiceCallback mCallback;

   public void bindCallback(ServiceCallback callback) {
       mCallback = callback;
   }

   public void unbindCallback() { 
       mCallback = null; 
   }

   // Somewhere in your code, call callback method to send data to Activity
   ...
   mCallback.updateStepValue(5, "15-07-2017");
}
```

Activity.java

```
public class Activity implements ServiceCallback {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    StepService service;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        editor = context.getSharedPreferences("preferences_key", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        // Once your service is running and assigned to service variable
        // bind activity to it to listen service callbacks
        service.bindCallback(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        service.unbindCallback();
    }

    @Override
    void updateStepValue(int value, String date) {
         editor.putInt("step",value);
         editor.putString("date",date);
         editor.apply();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.It surely be a better method.

Comment: Does it mean you keep an instance of your Activity in your Service event if the Activity is not used anymore? It doesn't create leaks?

Comment: That's it: you need to call a method to remove the activity's reference on `onDestroy()` or `onResume()` method like this:

`public void unbindCallback() {
       mCallback = null;
   }
`