# Saving 5 diferent product to sharedpreferences

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I am making a simple app which saves the products to database. But I dont want user to enter the all product data all the time. I want user to define max 5 products to make the saving them easier. I want to save the product size, color, price with sharedpreferences. But when I try to save the new product, old one is being deleted.

Is there a way to save 5 different sp?

Comment: better use SQLite database in this matter

Answer (score 0):

Basically check if you're initializing SP correctly and then putting the value and fetching it correctly using sharedpreferences.

**Initialization**

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); // 0 - for private mode
Editor editor = pref.edit();
```

**Storing Data in SharedPreference:**

```
editor.putBoolean("key_name", true); // Storing boolean - true/false
editor.putString("key_name", "string value"); // Storing string
```

**Retrieving the data from SharePreference:**

```
pref.getString("key_name", null); // getting String
pref.getInt("key_name", -1); // getting Integer
```

Check [this](https://www.journaldev.com/9412/android-shared-preferences-example-tutorial) if you want an example on this.

Comment: I can save and get data. no problem with it. The problem is I want to save 5 different sp. For example  for product A, B and C,  I want to save  size, color, price for each and I want to get values as " B.price "

Comment: Alright have a look at this page and you'll get your answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9054193/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-to-save-more-than-one-values